# CakePHP CakeTime utility niceshort localization in %jS

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, caketime

I use `CakeTime::niceshort()` and it works very well. I set correct locale values and set translate (po) files and I can see localized month, day names successfully.

But one thing is missing. When I use `niceshort()`:

```
echo $this->Time->niceShort(1387120620);
```

I get this:

```
Ara 15th 2013, 15:17
```

But this isn't valid for Turkish dates. I need this:

```
Ara 15 2013, 15:17
```

It is possible with these:

```
$this->Time->format($time,"%b %e %Y, %H:%M")
```

But I don't want to lose `niceShort`'s features. It gives short information if timestamp is close to now:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5/lib/Cake/Utility/CakeTime.php#L391

Is it possible to remove "th" and "nd" from dates without changing core lib ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [setlocale](http://www.php.net/setlocale) before calling `CakeTime::niceshort()`

```
setlocale("LC_ALL", "tr_TR.UTF-8");
```

You need to make sure they are properly installed on the server.

Comment: can you try to see it `setlocale` makes any difference?

Comment: I get error when I use `LC_ALL`. I added this, nothing changed: `setlocale("LC_TIME", "tr_TR.UTF-8")`

Comment: You can check this `echo $this->Time->niceShort(1387120620);`